# Cambiar Modelo de un JTable ya creado (JAVA)

Tags: java

es la primera vez que posteo en el foro.
Quisiera saber si alguien me puede ayudar para cambiar el Modelo de un JTable ya creado.
Es decir, tengo un JTable que al principio toda la tabla es NO EDITABLE, y quiero que al clickear un boton MODIFICAR, la misma tabla sea EDITABLE.
Intente llamando nuevamente la clase MiModelo(true), y seteando el modelo del JTable, pero me crea una nueva tabla, es decir me la remplaza por una nueva y vacia.
Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

```
    //Clase para hacer NO editables las celdas del JTable
    class MiModelo extends DefaultTableModel{
    private boolean aux;
    public MiModelo(boolean band){
        aux=band;
    }
    public boolean isCellEditable (int filas,int columnas,boolean band){
        return aux;
    }
}

    modelo=new MiModelo(false);     //Crear modelo de la tabla
    String [] columnas={"Articulo","Categoria","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","Aux"};
    Object [][] info={{"","","","","","","","","",""}};

    modelo.setDataVector(info, columnas);                                   //Le aplico los datos al modelo     

    tableClientes = new JTable(modelo);
```

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12776184/5215609

Comment: Muchas gracias, en el link encontre la solucion!